# How do I make a Leaderboard on roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

How do I make a Leaderboard on roblox?

Answer (score 2):

In every player needs to be inserted a value called 'leaderstats', using a script with the PlayerAdded event. Inside the leaderstats value, you can place IntValues - their name is what will show as the heading, and their value is what will appear as the player's stat.

To make those stats change, you need to add different functions and/or events to the script that created the leaderstats values.

Answer (score 2):

Insert a **script** into workspace, then in the code type this:

```
function Onplayerentered(player)

local leaderstats = Instance.new("IntValue")
leaderstats.Parent = player
leaderstats.Value = 0
leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"

local stat = Instance.new("IntValue")
stat.Name = "" -- Put name here in between the quotations
stat.Value = -- Put the starting Value#

end

game:GetService("Players").ChildAdded:Connect(Onplayerentered)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Bring up to roblox insert toolbar.
2. Select Leaderbord.
3. You can customize the script to fit your needs!

Comment: Maybe mention what parts doing what, and how to customize.

Answer (score 0):

Roblox leaderboards is a very long script, thankfully, the script allow us to easily add and remove leaderstats. To add a leaderboard insert a IntValue inside of the player object, to add a stat insert a IntValue inside the leadestats.

Most games on Roblox want every player to have the same leaderboard. So most people use a PlayerAdded event and create the leaderboard

Answer (score 0):

```lua
function Onplayererntered(player)

    local leaderstats = Instance.new("IntValue")
    leaderstats.Pareny = player
    leaderstats.Value = 0
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderboard"

    local stat = Instance.new("IntValue")
    statname = "Cash"
    stat.Value = 100

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a script into ServerScriptService and paste down the following code:

```
plrEntered = function(player)
local ls = Instance.new('Folder') --Leaderstats
ls.Parent = player
ls.Name = 'leaderstats'

local stat = Instance.new('IntValue', ls)
stat.Name = 'Money' -- Change to the value you want
stat.Value = 0 -- Add the starting value
end

game:GetService("Players").PlayerAdded:Connect(plrEntered)
```

Answer (score 0):

ROBLOX defines a leaderboard as an object that is named as 'leaderstats' and is located in the player object. A leaderboard statistic is defined as a value object inside the leaderstats object (Player>leaderstats>ValueObject). So lets write a function that creates a leaderboard with a 'cash' statistic for a player.

```
local function createLeaderboard(player)
    local stats = Instance.new("Folder")
    stats.Name = "leaderstats"
    local cash = Instance.new("IntValue", stats)
    cash.Name = "Cash"
    stats.Parent = player
end
```

Then we need to make this work. We need to connect this function to the 'PlayerAdded' event from the 'Players' object.

```
local players = game:WaitForChild("Players")

players.PlayerAdded:connect(createLeaderboard)
```

And that is basically it.
Note that line 3 in the code shown directly above is the equivalent of:

```
players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(player)
    createLeaderboard(player)
end)
```

The entire script would look like this:

```
local players = game:WaitForChild("Players")

local function createLeaderboard(player)
    local stats = Instance.new("Folder")
    stats.Name = "leaderstats"
    local cash = Instance.new("IntValue", stats)
    cash.Name = "Cash"
    stats.Parent = player
end

players.PlayerAdded:connect(createLeaderboard)
```

It is recommended to put the script in the 'ServerScriptService'.

Answer (score 0):

you first have to make a script inside the server script service and name it what ever you want, and write this in the script (make sure its normal script not local)

```
game:GetService("Players").PlayerAdded:Connect(function() --make the function start when new player joins
    local player = game.Players.PlayerAdded --make player variable
    local leaderstats = instance.new("Folder", player) --make new folder and set it's parent to the player
    local money = instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats) --create new value for the stat and set it's parent to the leaderstats folder (you can create as many as u want)
    money.name = "Money" --make the name of the value
    money.Value = 0 --make the value's value
end)
```

this block of code is simple and has many comments to explain it I wish it was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

```lua
function stats(plr)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("IntValue")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = plr
    
    local coins = Instance.new("IntValue")
    Coins.Name = "coins"
    Coins.Parent = leaderstats
end)
    
game.Players.PlayyerAdded:Connect(stats)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please format your code as code to make it easier to read, provide your question within the post body, and your current outcome and what you would like your outcome to be.

Comment: I formatted the code for you. I didn't **fix** your code though. You define `coins` but use `Coins` which is wrong.